# [Firebase/Core][I-COR000020] Error posting to Clearcut: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I am using Firebase for push notifications in iOS.

I am firing notification from Firebase console. How can I test notification using FCM registration token?

> New Message
>   Target-User Segment-Add Target- iOS App

I am sending message and response is displaying in logs.

```
{
"collapse_key" = "Bundle Identifier";
from =;
notification =     {
    body = Test;
    e = 1;
  };
}
```

I follow steps from the [Migrate FCM doc](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm).

I am getting this response but not able to see any notifications and I am getting also one error:

> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000020] Error posting to Clearcut: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2103, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.},

I am not able to understand what this error means, and why I am not getting notification and I am getting response.

Comment: Hi Krutharth, a couple of tips for posting questions. Questions pretty much live forever on Stack Overflow, so if you can write them as carefully as you can, it reduces the burden on editors. In particular, when referring to yourself as "I", please _always_ use a capital letter. Also, given that it is clear you need help, there is no need to add "please help me" to your questions - some readers may interpret that as a form of begging, and in any case we prefer succinct here! Hope that is helpful.